# C++ error for my 21 game with dice help please

Tags: c++

This is my `main.cpp`

```
#include "DiceTwentyOne.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
DiceTwentyOne game;
string play;
void playGame(string play)
{

    int turns = 0;

    while(play == "yes" && turns !=3)
    {
        cout << "Your score is: " << game.playGame(true);
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Would you like to roll?[yes,no]";
        cin >> play;
        cout << endl;
        turns++;
    }

    cout << "Dealers score: " << game.playGame(false) << endl;

    if(game.winLoss())
    {
        cout << "You win";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Dealer wins";
    }
}
int main ()
{
    cout << "Would you like to roll?[yes,no]";
    cin >> play;
    cout << endl;
    if(play == "yes")
    {
        playGame(play);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Have a nice day.";
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

`die.h`

```
#ifndef DIE.H
#define DIE.H
#include<stdlib.h> 
#include<time.h> 
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Die
{
public:
    Die(); 
    void changeFace(); 
    int getFace(); 
private:
    int faceValue; 
    void rollDie(); 
};
#endif
```

`die.cpp`

```
#include "Die.h"

Die::Die()
{
    faceValue; 
}

void Die::rollDie()
{
    int temp= (unsigned) time(0);
    srand(rand()%temp*((unsigned) time (NULL)
        *(unsigned)time(NULL)));
        faceValue = (rand()%((6-1)+1)+1);
}
void Die::changeFace()
{
    rollDie();
}

int Die::getFace()
{
    return faceValue;
}
```

`player.h`

```
#ifndef PLAYER.H
#define PLAYER.H
class Player
{
private:

    int turns, score;
public:

    Player();

    void setScore(int points);

    int getScore();

    void setTurns(int turns);

    int getTurns();
};
#endif
```

`player.cpp`

```
#include "Player.h"

Player::Player()
{
    score = 0;
    turns = 0;
}

void Player::setScore(int points)
{
    score = points + score;
}

int Player::getScore()
{
    return score;
}

void Player::setTurns(int turn)
{
    turns += turn;
}
```

`dicetwentyone.h`

```
#ifndef DICETWENTYONE.H
#define DICETWENTYONe.H
#include "Player.h"
#include "Die.h"
class DiceTwentyOne
{
private:
    Player player;
    Player dealer;
    Die die;
public:
    DiceTwentyOne();
    int playGame(bool truth);
    bool winLoss();
};
#endif
```

`dicetwentyone.cpp`

```
#include "DiceTwentyOne.h"
#include "Player.h" 
DiceTwentyOne::DiceTwentyOne()
{
    player;
    dealer;
    die;
}

int DiceTwentyOne::playGame(bool truth)
{
    player.setTurns(1);

    if(player.getScore()<21)
    {

        if(player.getTurns()<=3 && truth)
        {

            for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
            {
                die.changeFace(); 
                player.setScore(die.getFace()); 
            }

            return player.getScore();
        }
        else
        {

            while(dealer.getScore()<15
                && dealer.getTurns()<=3)
            {

                dealer.setTurns(1);

                for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
                {
                    die.changeFace();

                    dealer.setScore(die.getFace());
                }
            }

            int tempTurn = -1 * dealer.getTurns();

            dealer.setTurns(tempTurn);

            tempTurn = -1 * player.getTurns();

            player.setTurns(tempTurn);

            return dealer.getScore();
        }
    }

    return -1;
}

bool DiceTwentyOne::winLoss()
{

    if(dealer.getScore > 21)
    {
        return false;
    }

    else if(player.getScore() > dealer.getScore())
    {
        return true;
    }

    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I am getting this error and I've tried assigning a value to `getTurns`. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

> Error 1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall Player::getTurns(void)" (?getTurns@Player@@QAEHXZ) referenced in function "public: int __thiscall DiceTwentyOne::playGame(bool)" (?playGame@DiceTwentyOne@@QAEH_N@Z)  C:\Users\willr_000\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\A game of 21\A game of 21\DiceTwentyOne.obj    A game of 21

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ - I checked the duplicate - I didn't see where calling a method with the wrong signature was indicated.  Did I miss it?

Comment: @KevinDTimm This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12574403/1413395) covers mismatched signatures.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - I think the OP is going to give up long before he gets there - including it in the comments will be a great help to him (and others)

Comment: @KevinDTimm Well, that's why I've been upvoting  your answer :-P ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - thanks / {blushing face}

Comment: @KevinDTimm It's one of my most preferred dupes, and I'm mostly pretty sure it covers all of the situations that might cause these kind of errors. Surely additional hints be that comments or answers will be helpful for the OP.

Answer (score 2):

You call `playGame()` with a `bool` but it's defined as `playGame(std::string)`.